# Scrapy crawling finishes without crawling all start requests

Tags: python, windows, azure, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use the `scrapy` library to run a [broad crawl](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html) - crawl where I parse millions of websites. The spider is connected to a PostgreSQL database. This is how I load unprocessed urls before starting the spider:

```py
def get_unprocessed_urls(self, suffix):
        """
        Fetch unprocessed urls.
        """

        print(f'Fetching unprocessed urls for suffix {suffix}...')

        cursor = self.connection.cursor('unprocessed_urls_cursor', withhold=True)
        cursor.itersize = 1000
        cursor.execute(f"""
            SELECT su.id, su.url FROM seed_url su
            LEFT JOIN footer_seed_url_status fsus ON su.id = fsus.seed_url_id
            WHERE su.url LIKE \'%.{suffix}\' AND fsus.seed_url_id IS NULL;
        """)

        ID = 0
        URL = 1

        urls = [Url(url_row[ID], self.validate_url(url_row[URL])) for url_row in cursor]

        print('len urls:', len(urls))
        return urls
```

This is my spider:

```py
class FooterSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    ...

    def start_requests(self):

        urls = self.handler.get_unprocessed_urls(self.suffix)

        for url in urls:

            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url.url,
                callback=self.parse,
                errback=self.errback,
                meta={
                    'seed_url_id': url.id,
                }
            )

    def parse(self, response):

        try:

            seed_url_id = response.meta.get('seed_url_id')

            print(response.url)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

            footer = soup.find('footer')

            item = FooterItem(
                seed_url_id=seed_url_id,
                html=str(footer) if footer is not None else None,
                url=response.url
            )
            yield item
            print(f'Successfully processed url {response.url}')

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error while processing url', response.url)
            print(e)

            seed_url_id = response.meta.get('seed_url_id')

            cursor  = self.handler.connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO footer_seed_url_status(seed_url_id, status) VALUES(%s, %s)",
                (seed_url_id, str(e)))
            
            self.handler.connection.commit()

    def errback(self, failure):
        print(failure.value)

        try:

            error = repr(failure.value)
            request = failure.request

            seed_url_id = request.meta.get('seed_url_id')

            cursor  = self.handler.connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO footer_seed_url_status(seed_url_id, status) VALUES(%s, %s)",
                (seed_url_id, error))
            
            self.handler.connection.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

These are my custom settings for the crawl (taken from [broad crawl](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html) documentation page above):

```py
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100
CONCURRENT_ITEMS=1000
SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue'
REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 20
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.2
```

My problem is: the spider does not crawl all urls but stops after crawling only a few hundred (or few thousand, this number seems to vary). No warnings or errors are shown in the logs. These are example logs after "finishing" the crawling:

```
{'downloader/exception_count': 2,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 345073,
 'downloader/request_count': 1481,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1481,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1977255,
 'downloader/response_count': 1479,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 46,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 791,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 512,
 'downloader/response_status_count/303': 104,
 'downloader/response_status_count/308': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 22,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 64,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 113.895788,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 3, 11, 46, 31, 889491),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 136378,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 46,
 'log_count/ERROR': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'log_count/WARNING': 7,
 'response_received_count': 43,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError'>": 1,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>": 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 105,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 43,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 21,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/403': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 20,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 151,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 151,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 151,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 151,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 3, 11, 44, 37, 993703)}
2023-08-03 11:46:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Peculiarly enough, this problem seems to appear only on one of the two machines I tried to use for crawling. When I run crawling locally on my PC (Windows 11), the crawling does not stop. However, when I run the code on our company's server (Microsoft Azure Windows 10 machine), the crawling stops prematurely, as described above.

**EDIT**: Full logs can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/SgJfiezk). In this case the process stops after a few urls.

Comment: If you create a Python script that connects to PostgreSQL and then run the same query as the start_urls(), what result (# of rows) would you get in both machines after many executions of this script? How do you discover more links during the deep crawl? I'd add a `self.logger.info` inside start_urls to keep track of the # of items returned for troubleshooting. Please let me know what you get.

Comment: The logs say it finished because it ran out of urls from the start urls.

Comment: @LeandroRodriguesdeSouza I get cca 8 millions of urls (rows) in both cases. And I don't discover more links, I just want to crawl these urls without extracting other links. When I log the number of urls, I see the value of 8 millions.

Comment: @Alexander I get cca 8 millions of start urls, the crawler stops without crawling all of them.

Comment: @druskacik  If you want to post your full logs to a pastebin or something I can take a look but just based off of this there is no way to know what the issue is, unless the problem is unique to azure in which case I would have no clue.

Comment: @Alexander I added link to full logs in my post.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have solved the problem. It seem urls like `httpswwwwinchammotservicesltdcouk.co.uk` were breaking he `start_requests` loop because my validation function did not correctly check that the schema was missing for them. I'll write full answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Scrapy requires all start urls to have an HTTP schema, e.g. `stackoverflow.com` would not work, but `https://stackoverflow.com` would.

I used following code to validate whether a url contains a schema:

```py
if not url.startswith("http"):
    url = 'http://' + url
```

However, this validation is wrong. My data contained millions of urls and some of them were obviously degenerate or unconventional ([http.gay](https://http.gay/) seems to be a valid redirect domain) such as:

```
httpsf52u5bids65u.xyz
httppollenmap.com
http.gay
```

These urls would pass my scheme check even though they do not contain a schema, and they would break my crawling process.

I changed the validation to this and the problem disappeared:

```py
if not (url.startswith("http://") or url.startswith('https://')):
    url = 'http://' + url
```

Comment: Awesome. But did you find out why that worked on your local computer?

Comment: It seems that the pipeline just did not reach an url where it would fail. When the code run on my local computer for a few hours, I assumed everything is okay. The server was running for a longer time before the problem arised.